# Call threads with a class

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, class, for-loop, parallel-processing

I wan't to do parallel with the files that is in the class DictionaryTagger.
I pass 5 files in the class,

```
class DictionaryTagger(object):
    print_look = threading.Lock()
    def __init__(self, dictionary_paths):

      print('Hilo:', threading.current_thread().getName())
      files = [open(path, 'r') for path in dictionary_paths]
      dictionaries = [yaml.load(dict_file) for dict_file in files]
      map(lambda x: x.close(), files)
      self.dictionary = {}
      self.max_key_size = 0
      for curr_dict in dictionaries:
         #print(curr_dict)
         for key in curr_dict:
            #print(type(curr_dict))
            #self.dictionary = 
              if key in self.dictionary:
                  self.dictionary[key].extend(curr_dict[key])
              else:
                  self.dictionary[key] = curr_dict[key]
                  self.max_key_size = max(self.max_key_size, len(key))
   dictt = DictionaryTagger(['dicts/positive22.yml', 'dicts/negative22.yml', 'dicts/increasers.yml', 'dicts/decreasers.yml', 'dicts/inverter.yml'])
```

When I pass this, I have an error because ´dictionary_paths´ is not defined.

```
for i in range(3):
   t = threading.Thread(target=DictionaryTagger)
   t.demond = True
   t.start()
```

**init**() missing 1 required positional argument: ´'dictionary_paths'´

Answer (score 0):

You're receiving this error because the **init** function you defined as an argument ('dictionary_paths') without a default value.  You can solve this in two different ways:

1. Add a default value to the **init** function

   ```
   class DictionaryTagger(object):
       ...
       def __init__(self, dictionary_paths=[]):
       ...
   ```
2. Provide an argument when starting your [threads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread):

   ```
   default_dictionary_paths = []
   for i in range(3):
       t = threading.Thread(target=DictionaryTagger, args=(default_dictionary_paths))
       t.demond = True
       t.start()
   ```